# reading text and displaying

Tags: c#

I'm trying to see if a file exists. If it does exist, I want to read it. I have a `.dat` file that, when I install, I want the user to be able to edit and save.

This is what i have currently

```
 string path = "C:\test";
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {

            {
                richTextBox1.Text 
            }
        }
```

I'm not sure how to do it. I know how to do it with an open file dialog, but i want my program to read it without having to look for it, as my installer puts it in a place my program references. Is there a way to get it to load and be editable, then save the file without using either the save file dialog or open file dialog?

Comment: [Reading and Writing Text Files](http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/ReadWriteTextFile.aspx).  There are many ways to do this - the article is just the first one that popped up in Bing :)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but I see 2 questions here: 1. Where to store a file so that my program can access it without asking the user for a path? 2. How to open a file and read its contents? So what are you actually asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the File class to read all the lines at once and then add them to your RichTextBox.

Reading all lines from file to text box:

```
string path = "C:\test";
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    string[] fileContents = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    if (fileContents.Length > 0)
    {
        richTextBox1.Clear();
        foreach (string line in fileContents)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(line + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Writing all lines from text box to file:

```
string path = "C:\newTest"
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(richTextBox1.Text) == false)
{
    File.WriteAllText(path, richTextBox1.Text);
}
```

Comment: thank you ever so much :) :)

Comment: @user3363294 No problem...  Kindly click the check mark on my answer so that your question is solved. :-)

Comment: also would you know how to save this data loaded with just a save button ? without file dialog